# why kafka offsets are stored at consumer end of application?

Tags: apache-kafka

we have a kafka cluster and spark-streaming consumer. currently, the offset is stored at the consumer side on a data-store. when latest kafka, which is what we use, provides the feature to store consumer offset at broker level (on the `_consumer_offset` topic in kafka), what was the reasoning to store at consumer side.

One argument would be if kafka cluster goes down, we still have offset information. But if kafka cluster goes down, even messages are lost and no message can be replayed for a given offset.

I am missing something obvious, but can't figure it out. 
Thanks

Comment: Different consumers might have different offsets. Why should the server indefinitely store offsets for all possible clients? If you wanted to separately backup your offsets in Zookeeper, you are free to do so.

Comment: it stores a tuple of `(consumer_group, topic, offset)`

Answer (score 4):

As I understood, the core question you want to be answered is

> One argument would be if kafka cluster goes down, we still have offset
>   information. But if kafka cluster goes down, even messages are lost
>   and no message can be replayed for a given offset.

By storing offset ranges externally, it allows Spark Streaming applications the ability to restart and replay messages from any point in time as long as the messages are still alive in Kafka. So the decision to store offsets externally is likely not just based on recovery scenarios, but rather a general one.

This [link](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/) from Cloudera is very good

Comment: even in case of spark replaying the message from an offset, one could offset from kafka itself instead of an external datastore. The __consumer_offset topic in kafka is available for this purpose I believe.

Answer (score 2):

As it is mentioned in [Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#storing-offsets) the way you store commit offsets is dependent on how strict your reliability requirements are.

You may have a couple of options depending of which of streaming APIs you use.

1. DStream

First and the simplest one option is to configure external checkpoint location for stashing your data and consumer offsets. It allows you to easily recover *your spark code* after errors and produces idempotent output (handy when you write data to files). When you use DStream, you should *disable* `enable.auto.commit`.

Also you may commit offsets manually either to Kafka or to your storage (see examples from link above). In this case *you* have are responsible for making your outputs idempotent.

2. Structured Streaming

Here you have no option else than storing offsets at a checkpoint directory (e.g. HDFS). See [Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) (the same for Spark 2.2.x and 2.3.0).